# Validate empty TextBox, NumericUpdown and ComboBox with generic code in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, combobox, textbox

I have about 10 Forms like this below **ScreenShot**. 
[image]

I have to `reset` them and Validate if they are empty before `inserting` the data in to `database`.

Reset code :

```cs
void ClearAllText(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control field in con.Controls)
    {
        if (field is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)field).Clear();
        else if (field is ComboBox)
            ((ComboBox)field).Text = "Select ";
        if (field is DataGridView)
            ((DataGridView)field).Rows.Clear();//.Clear();
        else if (field is RichTextBox)
            ((RichTextBox)field).Clear();
        else if (field is NumericUpDown)
            ((NumericUpDown)field).Value = 0;
        else
            ClearAllText(field);
    }
}

private void action_Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearAllText(this);
}
```

Above code is working pretty much fine. But when I try to validate then it's not working properly.

```cs
private void action_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in panel6.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (c.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Some Values Are Empty or Not Proper... ", "Error Message",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So Far I have tried only `TextBox` and I have to validate `NumericUpDown` and `Comobox` too.

Comment: Why do you `break` when the first `TextBox` was found?

Comment: Because I dont want a MessageBox to appear multiple times. As far as it shows the error its work is done.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [DataAnnotations Validation Attributes in Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the controls do not have a default Reset or Empty Validation interface, you will have to manually implement the logic. At least refactoring the code you can reuse it in more places.

```cs
private void action_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //validation
    if (Controls.OfType<Control>().Any(x => !IsEmpty(x)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Some Values Are Empty or Not Proper... ", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    //insert statement
}

private void action_Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearAllText(this);
}

void ClearAllText(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls) Clear(c);
}

private bool IsEmpty(Control control)
{
    if (control is TextBox txt)
        return txt.Text == string.Empty;

    if (control is ComboBox cmb)
        return cmb.Text == "Select ";

    if (control is DataGridView dgv)
        return dgv.DataSource == null;

    if (control is RichTextBox rtb)
        return rtb.Text == string.Empty;

    if (control is NumericUpDown nud)
        return nud.Value == 0;

    return true;
}

private void Clear(Control control)
{
    if (control is TextBox txt)
        txt.Clear();
    else if (control is ComboBox cmb)
        cmb.Text = "Select ";
    else if (control is DataGridView dgv)
        dgv.DataSource = null;
    else if (control is RichTextBox rtb)
        rtb.Clear();
    else if (control is NumericUpDown nud)
        nud.Value = 0;
}
```